# Mistake in derived category computation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, coherent-sheaves, derived-categories

This might be a stupid mistake but I do not see where it is. Let $f:X \to Y$ be a morphism between smooth projective varieties (over $\mathbb C$), and let $F\in D^b(X)$, $G\in D^b(Y)$. Some version of Grothendieck-Verdier duality states that we have adjuctions
$$f^* \dashv f_* \dashv f^!$$

The right hand side says
$$\mathcal{Hom}(f_* F,G)={\mathcal Hom}(F, f^!G)$$
which is equivalent to
$$(f_* F)^\vee \otimes G = F^\vee \otimes f^! G$$

The left hand side says
$${\mathcal Hom}(f^*G,F)= {\mathcal Hom}(G, f_*F)$$
which is equivalent to
$$(f^* G)^\vee \otimes F= G^\vee \otimes f_* F$$
Dualize this, we get
$$f^* G \otimes F^\vee = G \otimes (f_* F)^\vee$$
Compare these two, we get
$$f^* G= f^! G$$
which is definitely wrong, but where is the mistake?
(Here everything like $f_*$, $f^*$, $\mathcal Hom$ is denoted as its derived functor)

Comment: You're drawing your final conclusion from $f^* G \otimes F^\vee = F^\vee \otimes f^! G$, right? You can only cancel a factor in an isomorphism of tensor products if that factor is genuinely invertible, i.e. a line bundle. As to why we can't pick an arbitrary line bundle, run through the computation, and get the isomorphism, I'm less sure; this is not my wheelhouse.

Comment: @TabesBridges Yes, but I think we can take $F=\mathcal O_X$ since this holds for arbitrary $F$.

Comment: Sorry I removed my previous comment because I may have misunderstood your definition of duality here (whether it is $\mathcal{H}om(., \mathbb{Z})$ or $\mathcal{H}om(.,\omega)$). So the problem really is that the adjunction is for the outer $\operatorname{Hom}$, not the inner $\mathcal{H}om$. The corresponding "adjunctions" are $f_*\mathcal{H}om(F,f^!G)=\mathcal{H}om(f_*F,G)$ and $f_*\mathcal{H}om(f^*F,G)=\mathcal{H}om(F,f_*G)$. In fact your equality $(f_*F)^\vee\otimes G=F^\vee\otimes f^!G$ does not mean anything since the left hand side is over $Y$ and the right hand side over $X$.

Comment: I can expand a bit on the isomorphisms but I would like to know what is the duality here. The duality $\mathcal{H}om(.,\mathbb{Z})$ does not interact well with $f_*$ and with the duality $\mathcal{H}om(.,\omega)$, you don't have $\operatorname{H}om(A,B)=A^\vee\otimes B$ but rather $(A\otimes B^\vee)^\vee$ and thus the rest of the argument is not quite the same.

Comment: @Roland Thank you for this! I see, I missed the $f_*$, and this seems like where the mistake is. For the duality, I think it means $\mathcal{Hom}(-,\mathcal O)$. I guess it does not interact well with $f_*$

Comment: You were talking about coherent sheaves ? So yes, this is really the $f_*$ missing which does not behave well with $\mathcal{H}om(.,\mathcal{O}_X)$.

Comment: @Roland Yes. I don't know, but is there any other world where it does not mean the coherent sheaves? And, why $A^ \vee \otimes B$ can be different from $(A \otimes B^\vee)^\vee$? I am just curious.

Comment: When I read your question, I though it was the category of constructible sheaves. As for the second question, take for example $DA=\mathcal{H}om(A,\mathcal{O}_X[n])$, and $A^\vee=\mathcal{H}om(A,\mathcal{O}_X)$. Then $DA\otimes B=(A\vee\otimes B)[n]$ whereas $D(A\otimes DB)=D(A\otimes B^\vee[n])=A^\vee\otimes B$. You see that for this duality, the two objects are different. But this is an important case : the Verdier duality on a smooth manifold of dimension $n$ is indeed with a shift $[n]$.

Comment: @Roland I see. Thank you for the explanations!